# Размещение элементов в линию

Tags: html, css, float, display, inline

```css
.design img {
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
  height: 55%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text {
  float: right;
}

h3 {
  color: #f7b419;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="design">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.1zoom.me/big2/719/321582-svetik.jpg" alt="clock">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h3>we help people to taake their business to the next level with user experience centric & conversion driven design</h3>
    <h2>design</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita ea officiis, tempore, consectetur vel, architecto quisquam odit id sit adipisci ipsa labore doloremque nemo saepe. Quae laudantium quia, asperiores beatae.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы картинка была слева, а текст справа, но не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас оба элемента не помещаются на экране, так как не стилизованные

1. Ваша модель - `float`

   Я обнулил стандартные стили браузера + добавил `width: 50%` и для
   всех элементов `box-sizing: border-box` для элемента с `img` и
   текстом:

   ```css
       * {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         box-sizing: border-box;
       }

       .design img {
         float: left;
         width: 50%;
       }

       .text {
         float: right;
         width: 50%;
         padding: 10px;
       }

       h3 {
         color: #f7b419;
         text-transform: uppercase;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <div class="design">
         <div class="img">
           <img src="http://www.1zoom.me/big2/719/321582-svetik.jpg" alt="clock">
         </div>
         <div class="text">
           <h3>we help people to taake their business to the next level with user experience centric & conversion driven design</h3>
           <h2>design</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita ea officiis, tempore, consectetur vel, architecto quisquam
   odit id sit adipisci ipsa labore doloremque nemo saepe. Quae
   laudantium quia, asperiores beatae.</p>
         </div>
       </div>
   ```
2. Новая модель - `flexbox`

   Модель полностью резиновая и удобна:

   ```css
       * {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         box-sizing: border-box;
       }

       .design {
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
       }

       img {
         display: block;
         max-width: 100%;
       }

       .img,
       .text {
         width: 50%;
         padding: 10px;
       }

       h3 {
         color: #f7b419;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-size: 2vw;
       }

       p {
         font-size: 1.4vw;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <div class="design">
         <div class="img">
           <img src="http://www.1zoom.me/big2/719/321582-svetik.jpg" alt="clock">
         </div>
         <div class="text">
           <h3>we help people to taake their business to the next level with user experience centric & conversion driven design</h3>
           <h2>design</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita ea officiis, tempore, consectetur vel, architecto quisquam
   odit id sit adipisci ipsa labore doloremque nemo saepe. Quae
   laudantium quia, asperiores beatae.</p>
         </div>
       </div>
   ```

Comment: Не путайте человека,  это flex. Flex-box уже давно устарела и её никто не использует.

Comment: @Zicrael  это для него новое раз он float ещё пользуется ..вы свой комментарий удалите

Comment: @Zicrael  ах да... забыл спросить - где это написано что устарело ?

Comment: Эта технология раньше называлась flex-box. Сейчас это просто flex. Почитайте разницу.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае `float` нужно применять не к `<img>`, а к `<div class="img">`:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.design .img {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.desing,
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
  color: #f7b419;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="design">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/50417922?wid=250&hei=250&qlt=80&fmt=pjpeg" alt="clock">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h3>we help people to taake their business to the next level with user experience centric & conversion driven design</h3>
    <h2>design</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita ea officiis, tempore, consectetur vel, architecto quisquam odit id sit adipisci ipsa labore doloremque nemo saepe. Quae laudantium quia, asperiores beatae.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень советую забросить использование `float` и начать читать o `flex`. 
Твое решение выглядит следующим образом:

```
.design {
    display: flex;
}
```

И картинка будет идти сначала, а после текст. Советую не задавать в таком процентном соотношении высоту и ширину картинки, для этого используют пиксели. Либо общепринятую фичу на подобии такого:

```
.design .img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Если будут замечания, указывай в комментариях я отвечу:)

**P.S.** : [Ссылка о технологии `flex` в `CSS`](https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/)